# Two /gen folders on Linux?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using IDEA 11.1 on Ubuntu 11.10 system. I renamed the main module via `Ctrl+F6` and after this IDEA created two `/gen` folders. Look at the image

[image]

The upper `/gen` has full path in the brackets (like `/disk2/work/project/...`). The lower `/gen` contains the path via desktop shortcut (like `/home/user/Desktop/work/project/...`). The both paths leads to the same directory.

The top-most folder has new name, while the lower folder (under the upper gen directory) has the name of a hard disk directory of a project.

Can anyone suggest how to merge this? It's making me a headache as IDEA does not recognize any new resource I add to this project.

I tried deleting all .idea and other conf files and recreating a project into the same directory (via Create Project with existing source files command), but it did not solve the issue.

I also tried to reverse to the previous state via "Show History" feature, but it was not possible. This step was not in the history.

PS. sorry about black-line parts but I was instructed to do so.

Comment: Probably caused by the symlink, try to create a new project in the actual path, not in the symlinked location.

Comment: You are right. I tried opening the project via full path, renaming and it did not happen. Any idea how to solve this issue? I've made a lot of changes into the projects before realizing this issue and I'd have to do it all over again (3 days of work).

Comment: Try to manually edit the source roots in the `.iml` file.